# how to link test probe with target actor

Tags: java, akka

In scala, it is very convenient to create a probe and then link it with an actor for test.

```
val probe = TestProbe()
val child = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[DependentChild], probe.ref))
```

from the point on, whatever is sent to child can be expected at probe as well.

In Java, there's no such API. simply make `probe` watch on actor will not make it receive all the messages arrive at the actor.

what is the equivalent in Java API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already an [issue created](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/17023) for adding such a forwarding actor. Note that one [such helper actor](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/fb34d4e83b42acd5a32c7808f70b8143aaa6d653/akka-testkit/src/main/scala/akka/testkit/TestActors.scala) was recently added. So if you are willing to create a PR, you are highly welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following ForwardingActor to provide this functionality (see comments for original source of approach):

```
/**
 * Simple actor that takes another actor and forwards all messages to it.
 * Useful in unit testing for capturing and testing if a message was received.
 * Simply pass in an Akka JavaTestKit probe into the constructor, and all messages
 * that are sent to this actor are forwarded to the JavaTestKit probe
 * Ref: https://gist.github.com/jconwell/8153535
 */
public class ForwardingActor extends UntypedActor {
    LoggingAdapter LOG = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);
    final ActorRef target;
    public ForwardingActor(ActorRef target) {
        this.target = target;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) {
        LOG.debug("{}", msg);
        target.forward(msg, getContext());
    }
}
```

And to use this:

```
JavaTestKit actor1Probe = new JavaTestKit(actorSystem);
actorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(ForwardingActor.class, actor1Probe.getRef()), "actor1");
```

Comment: this is the sample provided in the documentation, I wonder is here more elegant API

Comment: not that I'm aware of but love to know also if so :) I must have started using this before it made it into the docs, sounds like the Akka team must see this as the way to achieve what you are after.